# LEGO Mindstorms NXT projects

Tags: nxt, mindstorms

I have a LEGO Mindstorms NXT set and since I bought it I almost never used it. Sometimes I think I could do something interesting with it, but I usually either feel like just copying a previous made project or stuck with no ideas of what to do. The obvious answer probably is

> "If you try some project of other people at some point you start
>   connecting the dots and come up with your own ideas"

I would like to know if other people had this feeling in the past what they ended up doing.

As for background information: I have no experience with Technic sets, but have experience with computer science and math.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your "obvious" answer is right.  Given that you have a background in computer science and math, I'm certain you will be pleasantly surprised how fast you can go beyond connecting dots and come up with unique and innovative designs.  I admit being in the same position, but with an EV3.  It sat for almost six months before I really started working with it.  Based on my experience, I encourage you to commit to doing a few small projects to understand the potential.  Start small for some immediate gratification.  Log some experience, and you will start seeing ways to hack this little device.  This is a necessary step to doing something cool and innovative.  You gotta commit to building!

Answer (score 2):

If you just start trying to make a robot that does a perfect square path you will be surprised how hard stuff gets and how many things you can do... beyond all the imaginative design...

I have already written three posts on the subject and each time I have to kill new ideas so I can concentrate in what I have to do.

The first one is this http://thetechnicgear.com/2014/05/tutorial-using-motors-draw-square-mindstorms-ev3-lejos/ and as you can see it is a pretty basic robot.